# Create a plist outside Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

In our app we have lots of photos that we need to read while using the app, we have to also orgenize them into groups/categories.

1. this option is to make a `plist` with their names, and just put them into the app and read the plist.
2. create folders inside the app, order them inside, and read the specific folder.

Option 2 took me days and I couldn't even make it work reliably, and it also seems not the right way to work for some reason.

Option 1, the problem is that if you have 100 files you have to edit your `plist` every time again for a new file you add.

Is there a way to make option 1 outside of `xcode` so I can put all files in a folder on my mac, get their `plist`, and put this `plist` inside `Xcode` ?

What's the right way to achieve this ?

Comment: How about a proper file-naming pattern that will reflect categorisation? There are a lot of batch-rename utils that are easier to use than to make folders or plist files.

Comment: There are plenty of tools and libraries out there to manipulate the PLIST format but this is not the place to enumerate them. A quick search will find them for you. If that doesn't suit you then why not use some other format, such as JSON? Or perhaps even a database like SQLite?

Comment: Perhaps you could post your code for option 2 that isn't working and we could help debug that. That sounds easier and more concrete than suggesting random ways to build a plist.

Comment: So whats really the difference between folders option and assets catalog?

Answer (score 1):

plist is just a simple XML file. You can create the plist file and add to xcode as any normal file to the bundle and read it.

Answer (score 1):

macOS comes with two command-line tools for manipulating plists:

1. `/usr/bin/plutil` can convert a plist between formats. You might like this because you could write your photo catalog in JSON using whatever tools you like, then convert it to a plist. Of course, then you could just use JSON directly in your app…
2. `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` (note that `/usr/libexec` is not normally in one's `PATH`) can modify a plist in place, adding, removing, or changing entries.

Both of these tools have man pages (`man plutil`, `man PlistBuddy`) and substantial built-in help (`plutil -h`, `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -h`).

Answer (score 0):

First, you're making a false assumption. There is no need to use a `plist` file here. An ordinary text file listing the names will do just fine, and you can just make up your own format to dictate groups and suchlike. And that sort of file is trivially easy to maintain.

Second, your rather confused claim that "Option 2 took me days and I couldn't even make it work reliably, and it also seems not the right way to work for some reason" is just a cop-out. Folder references are not a difficult thing to use (you can configure them in the Finder, which is as simple as you can get), they do work just fine, and they are a perfectly reasonable solution here.